# Is there another way to add a flat plane across many vertices?

Tags: modeling

[image]My "boot" did not have face on the top (like the one on the left) so I added cylinder to the top and then used the "make manifold" feature of the 3D print tool. After that when I slide the cylinder up out of the way it leaves behind a boot with a nice flat surface across the top. I have two questions. If I only had the boot on the left (without the surface on top) how could I get a cursor to the center of area where I want the surface. How would I create the surface so the "boot" is "manifold"?

Comment: Select the vertices ring (Alt RMB) and fill (F)?

Comment: That worked, thanks. I thought I tried it before and ended up with a domed top instead of a flat surface.

Comment: I duplicated the issue I had before. It creates a dome of many surfaces if a subdivide modifier was added previously. Is there a way to have the modifier not affect the newly added "fill"?

Comment: Create a bevel along the top circle (press Ctrl B and drag)

Comment: I ended up applying the subdivide modifier and the making the face. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the vertices ring (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>) and fill (<kbd>F</kbd>)

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but I could have sworn I usually use `Alt`+`LMB` for selecting the ring...

Comment: You may be right as I've changed some of my shortcuts